# How can build relation between Rabbitmq-Server (as buffer for request interface) for my owm locla charm( process the requests)

Tags: juju, maas

The case is here:

I decide to use Rabittmq-Server as interface for request input and using my own charm fro connect to the rabitt mq and process the the requests!.

How can I relate this two ( my charm and Rabittmq-server ) together?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write a charm, a good place to start is with the official documentation:

https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/charms-deploying

Specifically in your case, you will need to add a requirement to your charm's [metadata.yaml](https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/authors-charm-metadata.html) file to indicate that it needs to access the RabbitMQ interface of the rabbit charm.

```
 requires:
  amqp:
    interface: rabbitmq
```

You will then need to create [hook files](https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/authors-charm-hooks.html) to manage the connection between your charm and rabbit. I would suggest also looking at the source for the [rabbit charm](https://jujucharms.com/trusty/rabbitmq-server-4/?text=rabbitmq-server), which will give you a better idea of what information it is possible to transfer using this service